# How to create sub accounts for my clients

Tags: magento2, customer-account, opensource

Trying to create sub-accounts for my clients, so their employees have access to store as well, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

So if you log into your backend and click on **System**, you'll notice a little section of the menu that looks like:

[image: User Permissions]

With the first and the last link, you can create User Roles and Users.

I recommend first making a User Role, call it "employee" or something, and restrict access to the resources it has. You might want to prevent your employees from changing important store configuration settings by accident.

Then, in the "All Users" page, you can create new users with a username, password, and email, and be sure to assign them the role you just created.

Comment: Hey @Jorge1o1 sorry i wasn't clear in asking my Question... actually im not looking for my employees to be able to go in to my admin panel, i am looking to add a function so my clients can add their employees to their registered account on our (my) website. will you be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to buy an extension, they're are a few out there including this one from [cminds](https://www.cminds.com/magento-extensions/multi-user-account-extension-for-magento-2-by-creativeminds/)

I have not tested it, so I cannot vouch for it.

Comment: Thank you @Haim, i appreciate it. I'm new to this industry... how much time would it take for me to do some like cminds as you mentioned? is it better to buy extension?

Comment: It will be much quicker to buy the extension but that's only if the extension is good and works out of the box

Comment: Okay Perfect, Thank you @Haim, I also have some other tickets made would you be able to help me with: [link(https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251879/how-do-i-allow-my-clients-to-upload-import-files-to-their-store)